# How do you make sure that the user inputs the correct type (list in my case) when creating an object class Python

Tags: python

Hi im trying to check the inputs when a new class object is created to determine if they are input correctly and if say "theMoves" is input incorrectly then do something like ignore it or attempt at converting it to a list.

```
Class Card:
    def __init__(self, theName,theHP, theMoves ):
        self.theName=str(theName)       
        self.theHp=int(theHP)
        self.theMoves=theMoves # [(),()..]


Class Deck:
#more code here
#When i try adding a card to the deck i get an index error because theMoves in the Card class arnt correct. It works with the c0,c1

def main():
    #c0=Card("Dave",454,[("Fieball",999)]) # works
    c1=Card("Bob",500,[("Fireball",999),("Flame",999),("Waterblast",499)]) #works
    #c2=Card("Peter",400,(fire,342))  # Fix 
    #c3=Card("Josh",300,waterb,22) #fix (maybe by just ignoring the moves after checking each varible)
```

Im wondering if there is a way so that if someone enters the information incorrect like I have done in "c2"/"c3" then it should either convert the values to match the format like c0 or c1 or just ignore the value all together.
If its easier, I dont mind just ignore theMove value if entered incorrectly but im not sure how to go about doing it ? When i looked online i seen someone mention the **new** method but im not too sure with python and objects on how I would go about doing it.

Thanks for your time and help in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `isinstance()`:

```
if isinstance(theMoves, list) and theMoves and isinstance(theMoves[0], tuple):
    pass
elif isinstance(theMoves, tuple):
    theMoves = [theMoves]
else:
    raise ValueError('Unexpected input type')
```

But in general programmers cannot handle all possible cases. Letting it break on unexpected input is not a bad design compared to trying to parse all inputs.

Comment: thank you ! i didnt think to use isinstance

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `isinstance()`, you can use type hinting, which gives more syntactic sugar.

```py
from typing import List, Tuple
def __init__(self, theName: str, theHP: int, theMoves: List[Tuple[str, int]]):
    self.theName = theName
    self.theHp = theHP
    self.theMoves = theMoves
```

As you can see, the syntax is much cleaner than what you would get with `isinstance()`.

If there is an import error, you can install/upgrade the official module with pip: `pip install --upgrade typing`.
The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: Syntactic sugar is a construct that gets converted to another construct before code generation. Type hinting is just *syntax* to provide information that another tool can use to verify (statically) that a value of the correct type is passed as an argument.

Comment: Right. Terminology misuse.

Comment: interesting thanks , ill take a look into it. Got the isinstance working now but ill take a look . So much i got to learn with python haha thanks !

Comment: If it works, you can mark my answer as accepted to give me some credit 